# PreferenceFragment Deprecated

Tags: android, android-fragments, androidx, android-preferences, kotlin-android-extensions

For creating settings page I used `PreferenceFragment` in my older project. But `PreferenceFragment` is **deprecated** in Android `API level 28`.

**What will be alternative of PreferenceFragment now?**

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using `PreferenceFragment` now we have to use **PreferenceFragmentCompat**

Implementation example inside Fragment:

```
public static class DemoFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);
    }
}
```

Please see official documentation of [PreferenceFragmentCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat).